# Сжатие лог-файла транзакций происходит не полностью

Tags: sql-server

В общем, нажимаю правой кнопкой по БД, выбираю сжать->файлы и далее выбираю журнал.

Мне показывается, что у меня 99% (120 гигов) доступного свободного места.

Ставлю галочку на "Освободить неиспользуемое место" и жму ОК.

Файл немного уменьшается. Захожу снова в это же меню и там снова 99% свободного места, а сам файл уже весит 90 гигов.

Это нормально? Или если я хочу реального сжатия в разы, то должен реорганизовать страницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала необходимо проверить нет ли чего-нибудь что мешает вам усечь файл журанала.

```
SELECT  name ,
    log_reuse_wait ,
    log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.databases AS D
```

Если значение `log_reuse_wait` равно 0, журнал базы данных может быть усечен.
Если нет, рашифровку занчения вы можете посмотреть [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms345414(v=sql.105)).

После этого выполните простую операцию (резервного копирования) обслуживания:

1. Бэкап лога
2. Фул бэкап
3. `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` или `DBCC SHRINKFILE`

Если и после этого файл не усечен то причина в физической структуре файла.

Файл журнала заполняется как буфер и может быть усечен только путем удаления конца файла. Если используемая часть буфера находится в конце файла, то она не может быть усечена. Вам нужно подождать пока активная часть не переместится от конца к началу файла. Как только это произойдет, вы можете запустить стандартный механизм сжатия.
Подробнее: [Как сжать журнал SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/).

Если вы хотите заставить активную часть файла журнала перемещаться от конца к началу буфера:

1. Выполните любую достаточно тяжелую операцию внутри транзакции и откатите ее, тем самым вы добьетесь перемещения "*указателя*" внутри файла.
2. Выполните шага резервного копирования, чтобы обрезать журнал
3. Выполните сжатие файла. Если активная часть журнала перемещена достаточно
   далеко, файл будет сжат.

Comment: Равно 0. Я кстати попробовал сделать реорганизацию до 2000МБ, но почему-то лог со 150гб только до 80ГБ обрезался.

Comment: А это по моему тот случай про который вы говорили: 
Cannot shrink log file 2 (***_log) because the logical log file located at the end of the file is in use.